# Use Canvas to turn non-transparent pixels white

Tags: javascript, image, image-processing, canvas

I'm looking for a way to take images (logos, app icons, etc.) and convert them to white (excluding transparency) using javascript/canvas.

Here's an example of what I'd like (using static images, obviously):
http://jsfiddle.net/4ubyj/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The canvas API has compositing methods specifically for things like "draw only on pixels that are not transparent in the original image."  This is much easier than messing with the image data.

## **[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nbwyvjog) example** (now with inlined image)

hat tip to @WilliamVanRensselaer's initial fiddle.

The composite operation you want is `source-in`, which means "draw the opaque parts of what I'm trying to paint only where they are on top of opaque pixels in the image being drawn upon."

HTML:

```
<a href="javascript:doIt()">paint non-transparent regions white</a><br>
<canvas id="canvas" width="600" height="200"></canvas>
```

Javascript:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById( "canvas" ),
    ctx = canvas.getContext( "2d" );

imgSrc = "http://d.pr/Td69+";
var b = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
var i = document.createElement("img");
i.src = imgSrc;
i.style.setProperty("display", "none");
i.onload = function() {
    ctx.drawImage(i, 0, 0);
}
b.appendChild(i);

window.doIt = function() {
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-in";

    ctx.fillStyle = "#ffffff";
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 600, 200);
}
```

[reference](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-canvas-element.html#dom-context-2d-globalcompositeoperation)

Comment: +1 for using `globalCompositeOperation` instead of messing with the image data. This should be gobs faster than the other (completely correct) solution.

Comment: This is perfect, ellisbben! Not only is it faster as Phrogz mentioned, but it also avoids origin permission issues, which makes it more applicable in various scenarios. Cheers!

Comment: Great answer. For anyone wanting to target the transparent pixels instead of the non-transparent ones, use the `destination-over` composite mode ([reference](https://drafts.fxtf.org/compositing/#canvascompositingandblending)).

Answer (score 0):

Here's something to get you started. This basically changes the pixel to white if the alpha is not zero, you can make modifications if you want though.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Q27Qc/

```
var canvas = document.getElementById( "canvas" ),
    ctx = canvas.getContext( "2d" );

// Put something on the canvas (can be an image)
ctx.font = "100px Arial";
ctx.fillText( "Google", 20, 130 );

// Get image data for part of the canvas (to see effects)
var img = ctx.getImageData( 20, 40, 80, 100 ),
    imgData = img.data;

// Loops through bytes and change pixel to white if alpha is not zero.
for ( var i = 0; i < imgData.length; i += 4 ) {
    if ( imgData[i + 3] !== 0 ) {
        imgData[i] = 255;
        imgData[i + 1] = 255;
        imgData[i + 2] = 255;
    }
}

// Draw the results
ctx.putImageData( img, 20, 40 );
```

Comment: No reason not to set the RGB of even the fully-transparent pixels to white. (Should test to see if it's faster to skip them or avoid the test.) Anyhow, I'd +1 you except that @ellisben has the far better solution.